# SQL : Query to get single row data in two rows

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table in below format

[image]

and I want output like this

[image]

that means i want to show

> Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4,Column 5,Column 6,Column 7

in **First row** and

> Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4,Column 8,Column 9,Column 10

in **Second row**

and main problem is i am having 256 columns and i dont want to run same query again and again.
So is there any way to solve this using loop or anything.?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by using a union query. Add the OrderKey column to maintain the ordering of your rows.

```
SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7, 1 AS OrderKey
FROM [TableName]
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column8,Column9,Column10, 2 AS OrderKey
FROM [TableName]
ORDER BY OrderKey
```

Comment: Better use `union all` - union could be slower and it does combine identical records.

Comment: Hello @DB101 i am having 256 columns and i dont want to run same query again and again.
So is there any way to solve this using loop or anything.?

Comment: Loops are rarely the correct solution to a set based problem. What is it that you are trying to achieve?